# Squid Proxy in Centos 6.8 Htpass Error

Tags: bash, proxy, centos6, vps, squid

I Tried to configure Squid Proxy server (ver 3.1.23), in my private server using Centos 6.8,
here my Squid Configuration

```
#A Port you would like to use
http_port 3128

acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7 # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10 # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80 # http
acl Safe_ports port 21 # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443 # https
acl Safe_ports port 70 # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210 # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535 # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280 # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488 # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591 # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777 # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440 20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0% 1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|?) 0 0% 0
refresh_pattern . 0 20% 4320
#Your Personal IP to allow without authentication
acl myclients src "my client IP"
#Allow this IP without authentication 
http_access allow myclients 


auth_param basic program /usr/lib64/squid/ncsa_auth /etc/squid/squid_access 
auth_param basic childred 5
auth_param basic realm Squid proxy-caching web server
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
acl ncsaauth proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow ncsaauth
forwarded_for off

#Enter your servers IP here
acl ip1 myip "my Server IP"
tcp_outgoing_address "my Server IP"

request_header_access Allow allow all 
request_header_access Authorization allow all 
request_header_access WWW-Authenticate allow all 
request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all 
request_header_access Proxy-Authenticate allow all 
request_header_access Cache-Control allow all 
request_header_access Content-Encoding allow all 
request_header_access Content-Length allow all 
request_header_access Content-Type allow all 
request_header_access Date allow all 
request_header_access Expires allow all 
request_header_access Host allow all 
request_header_access If-Modified-Since allow all 
request_header_access Last-Modified allow all 
request_header_access Location allow all 
request_header_access Pragma allow all 
request_header_access Accept allow all 
request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all 
request_header_access Accept-Encoding allow all 
request_header_access Accept-Language allow all 
request_header_access Content-Language allow all 
request_header_access Mime-Version allow all 
request_header_access Retry-After allow all 
request_header_access Title allow all 
request_header_access Connection allow all 
request_header_access Proxy-Connection allow all 
request_header_access User-Agent allow all 
request_header_access Cookie allow all 
request_header_access All deny all

#Allocate 3GB for Caching
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 3000 16 256 
#Maximum Cache Object 1GB
maximum_object_size 1024 KB 
#Use 1GB RAM for Cache 
cache_mem 1024 MB
```

when i tried to create username and password for my proxy using

```
touch /etc/squid/squid_access; htpasswd /etc/squid/squid_access admin
```

i got error

```
-bash: htpasswd: command not found
```

i don't know what to do to solve this problem, please guys help me out with this problem

Answer (score 0):

my guess you missed installation of **apache package** try to install **apache** **package** on your centos machine then execute htpasswd command it will works.

Comment: `htpasswd` is provided by the `httpd-tools` package on CentOS 6